# use-package and auto-complete, howto?

Tags: auto-complete-mode, use-package

How to use `auto-complete` with `use-package` and have `auto-complete` loaded later?

Following config is working, but how to get rid of the `defer 2`?

```
(use-package auto-complete-config
    :defer 2
    :bind (:map ac-mode-map
                ("M-<tab>" . auto-complete))
    :init
    (setq ac-auto-start nil
          ac-quick-help-delay 0.5)
    :config
    (global-auto-complete-mode t))
```

I tried `global-auto-complete-mode` and `auto-complete` mapped to global key map key `M-TAB` but both are not working.

Comment: Use `:after` instead of `:defer`. `(use-package foo :after bar)`

Comment: @fhdhsni thanks for the suggestion. I can't spot a package which I could use in place of `bar`. But the `:after` key is a nice solution for yasnippet which is pulled by auto-complete. (yasnippet takes some time to load and is the reason I want to delay auto-complete loading)

Comment: You seems to :bind `M-TAB` to ac-mode-map, which will be activated AFTER loading auto-complete-mode. Try deleting :defer line and changing :bind to global -- (("M-<tab>" . auto-complete))

Comment: @lurdan This, I already did, it is not working. I intended the sentence below the code to state this.

Comment: I'm sorry missing that. I've tested locally and update as an answer :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`auto-complete` checks if you are already in `auto-complete-mode` (in function `ac-start`).
But with lazy loading, when you call `auto-complete`, you are not in `auto-complete-mode` because it is not loaded yet.

So, you should call either `auto-complete-mode` or `global-auto-complete-mode` before you call `auto-complete`.

If you stick it to be loaded later, this snippet may help:

```
(use-package auto-complete-config
  :ensure auto-complete
  :bind ("M-<tab>" . my--auto-complete)
  :init
  (defun my--auto-complete ()
    (interactive)
    (unless (boundp 'auto-complete-mode)
      (global-auto-complete-mode 1))
    (auto-complete))
  )
```

I myself use `:demand t` to load immediately.

Note: `M-<Tab>` is not working but `M-<tab>` works

Comment: I like your idea, but there seems yet another problem. The key `M-<tab>` keeps bound to `completion-at-point` in scratch buffer and in `text-mode` to `ispell-complete-word` even with a minimalistic config run by `emacs -Q -l test-config.el` I don't get whats happening.

Comment: I do not want to use `:demand t` because in my config `auto-complete` pulls `yasnippet` and this takes some seconds to load.

Comment: please change the `:bind` line to `:bind ("M-<tab>" . my--auto-complete)`, then your code works. Reason: `Tab` does not work but `tab` is and double parentheses are not necessary.